# What is a good WLAN Router with DSL-Modem for OpenWRT

Tags: router, wlan

I'm looking for a WLAN-Router with integrated DSL-Modem (ADSL) which is supported by OpenWRT. Currently running a TP-Link WR4300 which is not having DSL integrated. The provider is suggesting FRITZ!Box 7490 (ADSL 2+ (ITU G.992.5) Annex B) but I really don't want to have non free (as in Freedom) hardware at this part of my home network.

Comment: **FRITZ!Box 7490** this model is also **VDSL** modem/router are you sure you need ADSL because if you have VDSL connection ADSL modem won't work ? If yes which Annex (A,B,J,L,M ?) do you need ?

Comment: @ivaan It's Annex B just updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Up to now there is no DSL/VDSl modem/router supported, because fo problems with the driver and the management of the modem itself that connects to the Internet Provider.

So, if you just want a name, I suggest you to look at ASUS DSL-AC68U because it supports a lot of OpenWRT features and it's directly maintained by ASUS. In sense that Asus bases its firmware on OpenWRT

Just to know it, FRITZ!Box 7490 has its own operating system that is NOT OpenWRT.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [FritzBox 7312](https://www.router-faq.de/?id=fbinfo&hwf=fb7312#fb7312).

**Reasons:**

- Supported by OpenWrt ([see](https://openwrt.org/toh/avm/fritz.box.wlan.7312)).
- Internal ADSL 2 / ADSL 2+ modem that is also seemingly working when installing OpenWrt (which is rare and I have not seen this explicitly stated with any other [FritzBox supported by OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/toh/start?dataflt%5BBrand*~%5D=avm), but it might still work with others as well).

  > "ADSL: should be working, tested @TestBuild (AnnexB ATM & PTM) → default: Annex A not enabled in Kernel" ([see](https://openwrt.org/toh/avm/fritz.box.wlan.7312))
- *Very* economical, as it is available used for <10 EUR incl. shipment (for example on ebay.de). Happens because older router models like this that came with people's DSL contracts are always very cheap because they are very much in oversupply.

Unfortunately, this router has only internal antennas and cannot be extended with external ones because there are no connectors ([see](https://frixtender.de/die-antennenhalterung-ohne-garantieverlust/frixtender-kompatibilitaetsliste/)). Also it has only 802.11b/g/n wifi (no dual band with 802.11a) and onlyone 10/100 MBit/s LAN port ([see](https://www.router-faq.de/?id=fbinfo&hwf=fb7312#fb7312)).

**Alternatives:**

I much prefer the [FritzBox 7330](https://openwrt.org/toh/avm/fritz.box.wlan.7330), which is available for just as little used and eliminates all these disadvantages: [dual-band wifi](https://www.router-faq.de/?id=fbinfo&hwf=fbfonwlan7330#fbfonwlan7330) and [external antenna option](https://frixtender.de/shop/router-liste/frixtender-set-7390/). But I can't yet confirm if its internal ADSL 2+ modem is supported by OpenWrt or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely true to say that there are no DSL modems supported by openwrt. Though some are definitely harder to flash with OpenWRT than others, requiring custom JTAG connections and opening up the router.

The Buffalo WBMR-HP-G300H will work with OpenWRT and support both annex a and b with ADSL 2+ (though NOT VDSL). However you need to upgrade via DD-WRT because of the way buffalo enforces encrypted images out of the box.  On the plus side, you don't need to open up the unit.

See: https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/buffalo/wbmr-hp-g300h